# Generate PDF with partial HTML content in server side with .net web api

Tags: c#, html, pdf, activereports, webapi

Our application frontend is angular and backend is .net web API 
we want to generate a pdf report for all products used by the user.
Here product description is HTML content so we need a way to render Html content and product information into pdf on the server-side.

Right now we are using the Active Reports section report to generate pdf without description because in Active Reports RichText only supports a minimal level of HTML tags we need much more. So we need a better solution to generate pdf with HTML content on server side .

Answer (score 0):

You can use [html-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf) module to convert your html into pdf. It provides bunch of ways to convert html into pdf. Here are the few of them:

```
let pdf = require('html-pdf');
pdf.create(html).toFile([filepath, ]function(err, res){
  console.log(res.filename);
});

pdf.create(html).toStream(function(err, stream){
  stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./foo.pdf'));
});

pdf.create(html).toBuffer(function(err, buffer){
  console.log('This is a buffer:', Buffer.isBuffer(buffer));
});
```

It also let you define [options](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf#options) to customize your page.